Sorting an Array from Depth first sort to breadth first order MIPS
For this project, i am tasked with switching an array from depth first sort into breadth first and vice versa in mars4_5, I had already did the depth first to breadth first as below.
.data
# Initial array in breadth-first order
breadth_array: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

# Space for depth-first array
depth_array:   .space 60  # 15 elements * 4 bytes

# String for printing output
newline: .asciiz "\n"
msg: .asciiz "Depth-first array: "

.text
.globl main

main:
    # Initialize the base addresses
    la $a0, breadth_array  # $a0 = base address of breadth_array
    la $a1, depth_array    # $a1 = base address of depth_array

    # Initialize indices for traversal
    li $a2, 0              # $a2 = breadth_array index
    li $a3, 0              # $a3 = depth_array index

    # Call the recursive function
    jal pre_order          # Jump to pre_order

    # Print the message
    li $v0, 4              # syscall to print string
    la $a0, msg            # load address of message
    syscall

    # Print the depth-first array
    la $t1, depth_array    # Load the base address of the depth-first array
    li $t3, 15             # Number of elements in the array
    li $t4, 0              # Index to traverse the array

print_loop:
    beq $t4, $t3, exit     # If index == number of elements, exit loop

    lw $a0, 0($t1)         # Load the current element of depth_array into $a0
    li $v0, 1              # syscall to print integer
    syscall

    # Print newline after each number
    li $v0, 4              # syscall to print string
    la $a0, newline        # load address of newline
    syscall

    addi $t1, $t1, 4       # Move to the next element
    addi $t4, $t4, 1       # Increment index
    j print_loop           # Repeat the loop

exit:
    li $v0, 10             # Exit program
    syscall

# Recursive pre-order traversal function
# Arguments:
#   $a0 = breadth_array base address
#   $a1 = depth_array base address
#   $a2 = breadth_array index
#   $a3 = depth_array index (passed by value, needs to be returned)

pre_order:
    addi $sp, $sp, -16     # Allocate stack space
    sw $ra, 12($sp)        # Save return address
    sw $s0, 8($sp)         # Save $s0 (depth_array base address)
    sw $s1, 4($sp)         # Save $s1 (breadth_array index)
    sw $s2, 0($sp)         # Save $s2 (depth_array index)

    move $s0, $a1          # $s0 = depth_array base address
    move $s1, $a2          # $s1 = breadth_array index
    move $s2, $a3          # $s2 = depth_array index

    sll $t0, $s1, 2        # $t0 = $s1 * 4 (word offset)
    add $t0, $t0, $a0      # $t0 = address of breadth_array[$s1]
    lw $t5, 0($t0)         # Load breadth_array[$s1]
    sll $t1, $s2, 2        # $t1 = $s2 * 4 (word offset)
    add $t1, $t1, $s0      # $t1 = address of depth_array[$s2]
    sw $t5, 0($t1)         # Store in depth_array[$s2]

    addi $s2, $s2, 1       # Increment depth_array index

    # Calculate left child index (2*i + 1)
    sll $t6, $s1, 1
    addi $t6, $t6, 1
    blt $t6, 15, call_left # Check if left child index is within bounds
    j skip_left

call_left:
    move $a2, $t6
    move $a3, $s2
    jal pre_order
    move $s2, $v0          # Update depth_array index from return value

skip_left:
    # Calculate right child index (2*i + 2)
    sll $t7, $s1, 1
    addi $t7, $t7, 2
    blt $t7, 15, call_right # Check if right child index is within bounds
    j skip_right

call_right:
    move $a2, $t7
    move $a3, $s2
    jal pre_order
    move $s2, $v0          # Update depth_array index from return value

skip_right:
    move $v0, $s2          # Return updated depth_array index

    lw $ra, 12($sp)        # Restore return address
    lw $s0, 8($sp)         # Restore $s0
    lw $s1, 4($sp)         # Restore $s1
    lw $s2, 0($sp)         # Restore $s2
    addi $sp, $sp, 16      # Deallocate stack space
    jr $ra                 # Return from function

with the result 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5, 10, 11, 3, 6, 12, 13, 7, 14, 15
and now i need to reverse it to work from depth first into breadth first and what i have reached is
.data
# Initial array in depth-first order (pre-order traversal)
depth_array: .word 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5, 10, 11, 3, 6, 12, 13, 7, 14, 15

# Space for breadth-first array
breadth_array:   .space 60  # 15 elements * 4 bytes

# String for printing output
newline: .asciiz "\n"
msg: .asciiz "Breadth-first array: "

.text
.globl main

main:
    # Initialize the base addresses
    la $a0, depth_array    # $a0 = base address of depth_array
    la $a1, breadth_array  # $a1 = base address of breadth_array

    # Initialize indices for traversal
    li $a2, 0              # $a2 = depth_array index
    li $a3, 0              # $a3 = breadth_array index
    li $t5, 0              # $t5 = level (initially root level)

    # Call the recursive function
    jal breadth_order      # Jump to breadth_order

    # Print the message
    li $v0, 4              # syscall to print string
    la $a0, msg            # load address of message
    syscall

    # Print the breadth-first array
    la $t1, breadth_array  # Load the base address of the breadth-first array
    li $t3, 15             # Number of elements in the array
    li $t4, 0              # Index to traverse the array

print_loop:
    beq $t4, $t3, exit     # If index == number of elements, exit loop

    lw $a0, 0($t1)         # Load the current element of breadth_array into $a0
    li $v0, 1              # syscall to print integer
    syscall

    # Print newline after each number
    li $v0, 4              # syscall to print string
    la $a0, newline        # load address of newline
    syscall

    addi $t1, $t1, 4       # Move to the next element
    addi $t4, $t4, 1       # Increment index
    j print_loop           # Repeat the loop

exit:
    li $v0, 10             # Exit program
    syscall

# Recursive breadth-order traversal function
# Arguments:
#   $a0 = depth_array base address
#   $a1 = breadth_array base address
#   $a2 = depth_array index
#   $a3 = breadth_array index
#   $t5 = current level

breadth_order:
    addi $sp, $sp, -20     # Allocate stack space
    sw $ra, 16($sp)        # Save return address
    sw $s0, 12($sp)        # Save $s0 (breadth_array base address)
    sw $s1, 8($sp)         # Save $s1 (depth_array index)
    sw $s2, 4($sp)         # Save $s2 (breadth_array index)
    sw $s3, 0($sp)         # Save $s3 (current level)

    move $s0, $a1          # $s0 = breadth_array base address
    move $s1, $a2          # $s1 = depth_array index
    move $s2, $a3          # $s2 = breadth_array index
    move $s3, $t5          # $s3 = current level

    # Load depth_array[$s1] and store in breadth_array[$s2]
    sll $t0, $s1, 2        # $t0 = $s1 * 4 (word offset)
    add $t0, $t0, $a0      # $t0 = address of depth_array[$s1]
    lw $t6, 0($t0)         # Load depth_array[$s1]
    sll $t1, $s2, 2        # $t1 = $s2 * 4 (word offset)
    add $t1, $t1, $s0      # $t1 = address of breadth_array[$s2]
    sw $t6, 0($t1)         # Store in breadth_array[$s2]

    addi $s2, $s2, 1       # Increment breadth_array index

    # Calculate left and right child indices in depth_array
    addi $t7, $s1, 1       # $t7 = left child index
    sll $t7, $t7, 1        # $t7 = 2 * left child index (left and right children)
    add $t8, $t7, 0        # $t8 = right child index

    # Check if left child index is within bounds
    blt $t7, 15, call_left

skip_left:
    # Check if right child index is within bounds
    blt $t8, 15, call_right

skip_right:
    move $v0, $s2          # Return updated breadth_array index

    lw $ra, 16($sp)        # Restore return address
    lw $s0, 12($sp)        # Restore $s0
    lw $s1, 8($sp)         # Restore $s1
    lw $s2, 4($sp)         # Restore $s2
    lw $s3, 0($sp)         # Restore $s3
    addi $sp, $sp, 20      # Deallocate stack space
    jr $ra                 # Return from function

call_left:
    move $a2, $t7
    move $a3, $s2
    addi $t5, $s3, 1       # Increment level
    jal breadth_order
    move $s2, $v0          # Update breadth_array index from return value
    j skip_left

call_right:
    move $a2, $t8
    move $a3, $s2
    addi $t5, $s3, 1       # Increment level
    jal breadth_order
    move $s2, $v0          # Update breadth_array index from return value
    j skip_right

but this just outputs1,4,10,15 and the rest is 0
I tried sorting the depth first array into breadth first, but the output is still depth first sort

Do you have a known working C or Java implementation?  If so, then follow along single step debugging each at the same time to see where the assembly version goes astray.  If not, then make/find one in C or Java, and be sure it works, the compare their execution.  Also, try with the smallest possible input, e.g. array size, there's no need to do the debugging with full 15 elements.
